# qt vim doesn't build on kubuntu

Tags: qt, vim, configure, ncurses, ubuntu

I've been banging my head against a wall for a week trying to build [qt vim](https://bitbucket.org/equalsraf/vim-qt/overview) from source on my Kubuntu 12-10 machine.

The build command I'm using is:

`./configure --prefix=/usr/ --with-features=huge --with-vim-name=qvim --enable-gui=qt`

Which gives me this error:

`checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.`

After much googling, the only solution I found was to have libncurses5-dev and ncurses5-dev installed, which I do. I also installed every generic ncurses dev lib in the apt repo, just to make sure. Alas, it generated the same error.

With all the above libraries installed, I tried the command with the tlib option:

`./configure --prefix=/usr/ --with-features=huge --with-vim-name=qvim --enable-gui=qt --with-tlib=ncurses`

Which generated this error:

`checking --with-tlib argument... ncurses
checking for linking with ncurses library... configure: error: FAILED`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `apt-get build-dep vim` to install all build dependencies

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! That's a apt feature - didn't know about it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `apt-get build-dep vim` to install all build dependencies